# Raspberry NOOBS: remote desktop / multiple workspaces

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B running under NOOBS. I have installed XRDP to be able to access the Raspberry from Windows.

The remote connection is working fine but whenever I launch an application (ex: Chromium) from Windows, I don't see anything happening. If I check directly on the screen connected on the Raspberry, I see that the application is running there.

It looks like whatever I launch on the remote desktop screen, the output goes to the native screen and I can't see it in the remote desktop window. I'm connected with exactly the same user on both sides.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry is known for not beeing compatible with any VNC Software.
You should try RealVNC first which comes with NOOBS. Make sure you have the latest version.

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server realvnc-vnc-viewer`

At your desktop select Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Interfaces.
Ensure that VNC is Enabled.

Now get your RealVNC Application for Windows and youre ready to go.

Another alternative is TightVNC, which works in most cases fine, too.

Comment: I managed to make it work in RDP. I found out that if I don't log in directly on the Raspberry, there is no hidden screen when I remotely connect and everything is displayed where it should.

Comment: I just tried XRDP and couldn't recreate your issue. When i start the Remote Desktop Connection i need to login with my userdata (standard: "raspberry" "pi" ) and i'm done. (I'm using Win10) Maybe you could reinstall your XRDP files and check its status with `sudo systemctl status xrdp`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I see: xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-09-08 16:45:40 CEST; 2 days ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
 Main PID: 493 (xrdp)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 15.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           ├─ 493 /usr/sbin/xrdp
           └─5364 /usr/sbin/xrdp

Comment: Your logfile sounds good so I can not help you further. Maybe it's an issue with XRDP or Noobs on a 4B. I can't tell. Maybe you just might reinstall XRDP `sudo apt remove xrdp
sudo apt purge xrdp
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot` and afterwards install it again. This helps me usually with most of my problems... :) Otherwise i refer to RealVNC again.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll give a try and if it doesn't work I'll use RealVNC. Thanks!